# Using codeigniter sessions like a superglobal to

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

FIRST OF ALL:
I'm trying to develop a class or a couple of methods (or just a way), to use in codeigniter, that is generic, easy and flexible, I need a way to pass a message to it, display, everywhere in the project, and erase it then. (and if is ajax, will be awesome)

Back in the time that i didn't used codeigniter, I use to have a class, to insert messages in a session, a very simple class, so i could display success messages and etc.
Here is the class that i want to bring to codeigniter, but I'm almost sure that codeigniter has a similar solution, but i don't know what to search.
I also would like I better solution than this one, because i tried to adapt to the way that codeigniter hands session, but didn't work

```
<?php
class Basic
{
    protected $erros;

    function __construct()
    {
        session_start();
        if(!empty($_SESSION['erro']))   // Session não vazia (tem uma array dentro dela ent?o)
        {
            $this->erros = $_SESSION['erro'];
        }else                           // Session VAZIA (tem que COLOCAR uma array dentro dela)
        {
            $this->erros = array();
            $_SESSION['erro']  = $this->erros;
        }
    }

    private function destruct()
    {
        unset($_SESSION['erro']);
        unset($this->erros);
        $this->erros = NULL;
    }

    private function add($string)
    {
        $this->erros      = $_SESSION['erro'];  // pega mais um
        $this->erros[]    = $string;            // adiciona no array
        $_SESSION['erro'] = $this->erros;               // coloca de volta na session
    }

    public function add_error($data)
    {
        if(empty($data))return true;
        if(is_array($data))
        {
            foreach ($data as $value)
            {
                $this->add($value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->add($data);
        }
    }

    public function return_errors()
    {
        $erros = $this->erros;
        $this->destruct();
        return $erros;
    }

    public function check_ok()
    {
        return ($this->erros == NULL)?true:false;
    }

    public function show_errors()
    {
        $erros = $this->erros;
        print_r($erros);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my puny attempt to convert it to use codeigniter sessions

```
<?php
function __construct()
{
    if(!empty($this->session->userdata('my_msgs'))) // Session n?o vazia (tem uma array dentro dela ent?o)
    {
        $this->msg = $this->session->userdata('my_msgs');
    }else                           // Session VAZIA (tem que COLOCAR uma array dentro dela)
    {
        $this->msg = array();
        $this->session->set_userdata('my_msgs', $this->msg);
    }
}

function destruct()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('my_msgs');
    $this->msg = NULL;
    unset($this->msg);
}

function add($string)
{

    $this->msg      = $this->session->userdata('my_msgs');      // pega mais um
    $this->msg[]    = $string;                                  // adiciona no array
    $this->session->set_userdata('my_msgs', $this->msg);        // coloca de volta na session
}

function add_msg($data)
{
    if(empty($data))return true;
    if(is_array($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $value)
        {
            $this->add($value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->add($data);
    }
}

function return_msg($keep = FALSE)
{
    $msg = $this->msg;
    if($keep == FALSE)
    {
        $this->destruct();
    }
    return $msg;
}

function check_ok()
{
    return ($this->msg == NULL)?true:false;
}

function show_msgs()
{
    $msg = $this->msg;
    print_r($msg);
}
```

sorry about the bad English, not a native speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your previous code is using native session driver (`session_start()`), while codeigniter is using `cookies`.

If you just need to prepare some message, display and then destroy it immediately, [flashdata](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) would be probably fit.

If you need to create your own custom class, just take a look this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html, One that most important is a way to get codeigniter instance:

```
$var =& get_instance();
```

end then now you can use CI session in your class:

```
$var->session->set_userdata('something');
```

Your class might be look like:

```
<?php
 class Your_class {
    function __construct() 
    {
        $CI =& get_instance(); //get CI instance

        if( ! $CI->session->userdata('my_msgs'))
        {
             $this->msg = $CI->session->userdata('my_msgs');
        } else {
             $this->msg = array();
             $CI->session->set_userdata('my_msgs', $this->msg);
        }
     }

     //and soon ...
```

Comment: I saw flahsdata before, but don't know how to use it, if i rly need this instance,then "this" should be the problem them, thanks